# Error: could not determine PostgreSQL version from '10.3' ebdata

Tags: python

I'm trying since hours to install ebdata, i need it to extract street addresses from text, but the installation failed all the time with:

Any ideas for a solution?

Here is the full log:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install ebdata
Collecting ebdata
Using cached ebdata-1.2.tar.gz
Collecting django>=1.3.1 (from ebdata)
Using cached Django-1.11.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ebpub>=1.2 (from ebdata)
Using cached ebpub-1.2.tar.gz
Collecting lxml (from ebdata)
Using cached lxml-4.2.0-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
Collecting beautifulsoup (from ebdata)
Using cached BeautifulSoup-3.2.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: chardet in c:\python27\lib\site-packages 
(from 
ebdata)
Collecting feedparser (from ebdata)
Using cached feedparser-5.2.1.zip
Collecting httplib2 (from ebdata)
Using cached httplib2-0.10.3.tar.gz
Collecting xlrd (from ebdata)
Using cached xlrd-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from 
django>=1.3.1->ebdata)
Collecting django-static (from ebpub>=1.2->ebdata)
Using cached django_static-1.5.6-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting GDAL (from ebpub>=1.2->ebdata)
Using cached GDAL-2.2.3.tar.gz
Collecting pyyaml (from ebpub>=1.2->ebdata)
Using cached PyYAML-3.12-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
Collecting psycopg2<2.4.2,>=2.0 (from ebpub>=1.2->ebdata)
Using cached psycopg2-2.4.1.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
running egg_info
creating pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info
writing pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg- 
info\dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

Error: could not determine PostgreSQL version from '10.3'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
c:\users\elizav~1.koz\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-oytara\psycopg2\
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: could not determine PostgreSQL version from '10.3' - Django on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49291428/error-could-not-determine-postgresql-version-from-10-3-django-on-heroku)

Comment: That's different version and situation.