# ImportError: symbol __res_maybe_init version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference

Tags: python, django, python-import, psycopg2

I'm running an installation script that installs a number of different python packages. The one that is getting stuck on is `psycopg2`. The script attempts to install version `2.6.1`. But I run into the error:

```
Error: could not determine PostgreSQL version from '10.10'
```

I figured it has something to do with the version of `psycopg2` that's incompatible with `postgresql` version `10.10`. Is this an invalid conclusion?

Assuming my conclusion of version incompatibility is correct I changed the installation version of `psycopg2` to `2.7`. By doing that the error above went away.

However, when I run:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:888
```

I get the error:

```
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/nova/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/postgres/apps.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .signals import register_hstore_handler
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/nova/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/postgres/signals.py", line 1, in <module>
    from psycopg2 import ProgrammingError
  File "/home/mark/.virtualenvs/nova/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: /home/mark/.virtualenvs/nova/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/./libresolv-2-c4c53def.5.so: symbol __res_maybe_init version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference
```

This makes me think that, maybe version `2.6.1` is probably the version that I needed to use because it's complaining about `psycopg2`?

How do I fix the problem such that I can run the Django development server without the above error?

Comment: Did you install psycopg2 as describe at pypi or what install script are you talking about? https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/

Answer (score 7):

update psycopg2 to 2.7.3.1/2 and this error would go away like here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49292261/1816541

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this in the past. 
What I did is modify the psycopg2 version in pip (not sure what your script is using for versioning packages) to 2.7
I also verified it can work well with 2.5.9

Officially there is no backward compatibility fix https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/594#issuecomment-331172198